# AST for UML Activity diagram

Tags: java, compiler-construction, uml, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently doing a project to convert uml diagrams to java code,in one of the step I have to create an ast for general activity diagram and write a java code for the ast. The problem is I am not sure how to represent it in java code to accept any activity diagram as an input. Please need some help.

This is the meta-model of a general activity diagram, I want to represent this diagram as a java code to accept inputs.

[Activity Diagram Metamodel](http://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/~swt/agtive-contest/UML-to-CSP.pdf)

The first diagram on the second page of the pdf

Answer (score 1):

What tool are you using to create your activity diagrams?  Most will provide an API to query models and/or an XMI export*.  In either case you don't get an AST as such, more an Object structure of your model.  But it's still pretty easy to iterate that structure and generate code.

One option worth considering is the [Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/).  There are tools available for both creating diagrams (e.g. [Papyrus](http://eclipse.org/papyrus/)) and a multitude of options for generating code from models (e.g. [Acceleo](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/)) - have a look at the ['Model to Text'](http://eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/) (M2T) sub-project.

Even if you decide to use another tool for diagram creation, it's possible to use Eclipse M2T for code generation; most tools will export XMI in the eclipse dialect.

hth.

--

*XMI is the 'standard' for UML model interchange.  It was plagued with inconsistency in interpretation originally, and there are still some problems among tools today.  However: it is an XML dialect so even if tool B can't directly import XMI from tool A, it's usually possible to convert between the two.